# Natural Logarithm of a Negative Number

Tags: logarithms

I am trying to find the genetic distance between two DNA sequences using Kimura (K80) model, and the formula contains natural logarithm, after calculating the required Q and P's needed, my solution looks like this:
[Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukxqL.png)
Since, natural logarithm of a negative number does not exist, how can I solve that equation?

Comment: I am not sure about the calculations but $\ln(a) + ln(b) = \ln (a \cdot b)$, in your case both $a$ and $b$ a negatives making $a \cdot b$ positive.

Answer (score 1):

maybe use that for $x<0$: $$ln(x) = i\pi + ln(|x|)$$